# Angular directive for D3 datamap rendering only once

Tags: angularjs, svg, d3.js, angular-directive, datamaps

So, I made an Angular directive which renders a D3 datamap in an HTML template. I pass the data to the directive via a 'data' attribute. The problem I am facing is that the map displays perfectly when the page is loaded for the first time. However, when I come back to the template by navigating from other templates (routing done through 'ui-route'), the map doesn't get rendered and there is no error in the console either. **Here's my directive**:

```
app.directive('stabilityMap', function() {
    var containerid = document.getElementById('world-map-container');
    var margin = 20,
        padding = 50,
        width = containerid.offsetWidth - margin;
        height = containerid.offsetHeight - margin;
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {
            data: '=',
        },
        link : function(scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.$watch('data', function(newVal, oldVal) {   
                var colorScale = d3.scale.linear().domain([50, 100]).range(['#ff0000', '#280000']);
                var Fills = {defaultFill: '#ddd'};
                var Data = {};
                var countries = Datamap.prototype.worldTopo.objects.world.geometries;
                for(var i = 0; i < newVal.length; i++) {
                    for (var j = 0; j < countries.length; j++) {
                        if(countries[j].properties.name == newVal[i].Country) {
                            Fills[countries[j].id] = colorScale(newVal[i]['Stability Index']);
                            Data[countries[j].id] = { fillKey : countries[j].id};
                        }
                    }
                }
                var map = new Datamap({
                    element: containerid,
                    responsive: true,
                    projection: 'mercator',
                    setProjection: function(element) {
                                    var projection = d3.geo.mercator()
                                      .center([0, padding])
                                      .scale(105)
                                      .translate([element.offsetWidth / 2, element.offsetHeight / 2 - 70]);
                                    var path = d3.geo.path()
                                      .projection(projection);
                                    return {path: path, projection: projection};
                                  },
                    fills: Fills,
                    data: Data
                })
                d3.select(window).on('resize', function() {
                    map.resize();
                });
            })
        }
    }
})
```

**Here's my angular controller for the template:**

```
app.controller('CountryCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {
    $scope.countriesData = [
        {'Country': 'Australia', 'Stability Index':'85'},
        {'Country':'United States of America', 'Stability Index':'90'},
        {'Country':'Russia', 'Stability Index':'70'},
        {'Country':'India', 'Stability Index':'84.2'},
        {'Country':'China', 'Stability Index':'50'}
    ]
}]);
```

**Here's the HTML template:**

```
<div class="row" id="world-map">
    <div stability-map data="countriesData" id="world-map-container">
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is the screenshot when the page is loaded first:

[image: when page/website loaded first]

And the empty container after I come back to the page after navigating from some other template of the website.

[image: Empty container that should contain the svg]

Any idea what's happening?

Answer (score 0):

the map doesnt get rendered again, because the function is only run once, when the code is first executed. I suggest you wrap your creation of the map inside a function and call that function every time you load the page (from the controller).

```
$scope.renderMap = function() { 
   var map = new Datamap({
                    element: containerid,
                    responsive: true,
                    projection: 'mercator',
                    setProjection: function(element) {
                                    var projection = d3.geo.mercator()
                                  .center([0, padding])
                                  .scale(105)
                                  .translate([element.offsetWidth / 2, element.offsetHeight / 2 - 70]);
                                var path = d3.geo.path()
                                  .projection(projection);
                                return {path: path, projection: projection};
                              },
                    fills: Fills,
                    data: Data
                })
}
```

The code you will then need to render the map is the following:

```
$scope.renderMap()
```

I hope this helps.

xoxo

Comment: Well, the thing is the directive I created also had code (along with the map code) to create a linearGradient. And this linearGradient gets rendered when navigating from other parts, but the map doesn't. Also, I know I can do this in the controller, I just wanted to use a directive for reusability purpose.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer to this. You have to put your variables inside your link function. This means moving

```
var containerid = document.getElementById('world-map-container');
var margin = 20,
    padding = 50,
    width = containerid.offsetWidth - margin;
    height = containerid.offsetHeight - margin;
```

right inside your link function. This solved the problem for me.